# What is the term for a missing feature in a descendant that was present in an ancestor which defines a clade?

Tags: zoology

Examples include:

- A snake does not have legs, but is still considered a tetrapod as it is a descendant of animals with four legs
- Bdelloidea (class of rotifera) can only reproduce asexually, but is still considered an animal as it has ancestors that reproduced sexually
- Star fishes have pentaradial symmetry, yet they are considered bilateralians as their ancestors were bilaterally symmetrical

Comment: I've changed the headline from _What is the term for a missing feature in a descendant that was present in an ancestor and defines a clade?_ because it could be read as saying the feature defines the clade. Since clades are defined by an ancestral organism and not a particular feature, I changed it to read _in an ancestor which defines a clade?_, which I presume was intended.

Comment: The earliest snakes still had limbs: https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/a-fossil-snake-with-four-legs

Comment: Loss-based apomorphy or apomorphy?

Comment: Secondary loss?